# Help to implement a ZipWithRatio extention method

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I'm trying to find a elegant way to write a extention method that might be called MergeWithRatio or ZipWithRatio.

I expect it to have this signature..

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWithRatio<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> mergeSequence, int ratio)
{
  ..
}
```

Example first.

```
var source   = new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var mergeSeq = new[]{100,200};
var result = source.MergeWithRatio(mergeSeq, 3).ToArray();
```

result now contains [1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 200, 5, 6, 100, 7, 8, 200, 9]

Summing up: 
The mergeSeq is looped when/if finished and the yielding stops when 'source' is empty.

If possible I would prefere if the solution was lazy but it is not a requirement.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: You haven't specified whether the result can/should end with an item from `mergeSequence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work and returns the expected output:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWithRatio<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> mergeSequence, int ratio)
{
    int currentRatio  = 1;
    bool mergeSequenceIsEmpty = !mergeSequence.Any();

    using (var mergeEnumerator = mergeSequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
            currentRatio++;
            if (currentRatio == ratio &&  !mergeSequenceIsEmpty)
            {
                if (!mergeEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    mergeEnumerator.Reset();
                    mergeEnumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                yield return mergeEnumerator.Current;
                currentRatio = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `source`'s iterator will be properly disposed by `foreach`, don't forget to also dispose `mergeEnumerator` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWithRatio<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> mergeSequence, int ratio)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    if (mergeSequence == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("mergeSequence");
    }

    if (ratio <= 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ratio must be greater one.");
    }

    return MergeWithRatioImpl(source, mergeSequence, ratio);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> MergeWithRatioImpl<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> mergeSequence, int ratio)
{
    bool mergeSequenceContainsElements = true;
    int i = 1;
    ratio--;

    using (var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var mergeSequenceEnumerator = mergeSequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return sourceEnumerator.Current;

            if (i++ % ratio == 0)
            {
                if (!mergeSequenceEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    // ToDo: Should we cache the current values for the case the
                    //       enumerator can't be reset?
                    mergeSequenceEnumerator.Reset();
                    mergeSequenceContainsElements = mergeSequenceEnumerator.MoveNext();
                }

                if (mergeSequenceContainsElements)
                {
                    yield return mergeSequenceEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for error checking and separating the deferred execution into a separate method.

Comment: @juharr: Yes, thanks to Jon and is [EduLinq series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWithRatio<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> mergeSequence, int ratio)
{
    using (IEnumerator<T> sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator(), 
                          mergeSequenceEnumerator = mergeSequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return sourceEnumerator.Current;
            i++;
            if (i == ratio)
            {
                if (!mergeSequenceEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    mergeSequenceEnumerator.Reset();
                    mergeSequenceEnumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                yield return mergeSequenceEnumerator.Current;
                i = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Plus some checks on `mergeSequenceEnumerator.MoveNext()`, `ratio` input value`, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose both iterators, if possible.